Python randomly stops writing to file
I am reading from serial ports and writing the output to a text file. Yet no matter where I put cal, the program will stop reading from it or writing the output after a few seconds. The mm and light related data works and runs fine.
with open(path + r"\mm_response.txt", "w") as f, open(path + r"\cal_response.txt", "w") as h, open(path + r"\light_response.txt", "w") as g:
        while main.a == 1:
            #continuosly send 89 hex command to receive data back from mm
            ser_mm.write(serial.to_bytes([0x89]))
            #read serial data
            if lux == 1 and cal == 1: 
                response_mm = ser_mm.readline(12)
                response_light = ser_light.read(16)
                response_cal = ser_cal.readline()
            elif lux == 1 and cal == 0: 
                response_mm = ser_mm.readline(12)
                response_light = ser_light.read(16)
                response_cal = 0
            elif lux == 0 and cal == 1: 
                response_mm = ser_mm.readline(12)
                response_light = 0
                response_cal = ser_cal.readline()
            elif lux == 0 and cal == 0: 
                response_mm = ser_mm.readline(12)
                response_light = 0
                response_cal = 0
            else: 
                response_mm = ser_mm.readline(12)
                response_light = 0
                response_cal = 0
            #remove special characters from multimeter data
            response_mm = str(response_mm)
            response_mm = ''.join(letter for letter in response_mm if letter.isalnum())
            #remove special characters from light data
            response_light = str(response_light)
            response_light = ''.join(letter for letter in response_light if letter.isalnum())
            #remove special characters from multimeter data
            response_cal = str(response_cal)
            response_cal = ''.join(letter for letter in response_cal if letter.isalnum())
            #record null value from light meter as zero reading
            response_light = response_light.replace("x19", "0")
            #remove special characters from light data
            response_cal = response_cal.replace("b", "0")
            #record values
            g.write(response_light)
            g.flush()
            f.write(response_mm)
            f.flush()
            h.write(response_cal)
            h.flush()
            #add delay so there aren't thousands of data points
            time.sleep(0.0001)

I have tried removing the delay, increasing the baud rate, adding print statements in the loops to see if it is getting stuck somewhere. Everything seems to be working as it should, yet the cal data is not reading/writing properly. If I have a program with similar code and just the cal data it works fine, so I am not sure what the issue is.

The obvious explanation is that ser_cal.readline() returns a blank string.  Have you tried printing that variable to see what it is?

Thanks for that, just tried it. It is not returning a blank string, but it is very delayed. It's returning values15-30 seconds after the value was actually measured by the device.

I added ser_cal.reset_input_buffer() and ser_cal.reset_output_buffer() and it seems to have solved the delay. There is still delay, but a lot less.

presume the baud rates are same for sender/receiver

The baud rates should be correct. If it weren't I think the data would look like random characters. The data is in the correct format, just delayed.
